# How to make Messages send button icon?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton, icons

How do I make a button that functions & looks like the send message button in the iPhone Messages app.

I want an icon or code that draws the button in its different states:

disabled:

[image: Messages send button disabled]

enabled:

[image: Messages send button enabled]

and selected:

[image: Messages send button selected]

Comment: You can do this natively with UIButton states... given your rep, kinda confused by the simplicity of the question — maybe you're asking something different?

Comment: I know how to change things by state, but for each state, how do I make the up-arrow icon that goes inside the button and give the button a background color? Should I use a PNG or draw it? If PNG, how do I make the PNG? If draw, how do I draw?

Comment: PNG with alpha channel would be the easiest for sure. You can then use the tint property on the UIButton to dynamically change the color via code.

Comment: Sweet! That worked! Thanks! Despite my extraordinary reputation, I didn't know that `tintColor` did that. Thanks! :-)